# MVC Model required field, sometimes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to reuse my model in my MVC project. However in some instances the model needs to have all its fields filled and in others only some fields need to be filled. I applied [Required] attribute to fields that are required in all cases. But what about others? Is there a way to make those other fields required in just certain instances?

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it a "hacky" kind of way by creating a custom validator that you trigger with, say, another field in the model.  But that seems odd.  I'd really opt for having a custom VM for each of the cases: one where required, one where not.  You can then use one of many tools to map from your VM to your Model if you're concerned with having to copy fields over.  Look at Automapper and ServiceStack.Text (which has a `TranslateTo` method) for two examples of simple mappers.